# How to execute a list of observables in parallel and collect the result

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

If there is a list of Observables for example:

```
Observable<Msg> obs1 = getObs1();
Observable<Msg> obs2 = getObs2();

List<Observable<Msg>> listOfObs = new ArrayList<Observable<Msg>>();
listOfObs.add(obs1);
listOfObs.add(obs2);

Observabke allObs = Observable.zip(observableListOfEntries, new FuncN<List<Message2>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Msg> call(Object... args) {
            List<Msg> message2List = new ArrayList<Msg>();
            for (Object obj : args) {
                message2List.add((Message2) obj);
                Log.d("Msg>>>", ((Msg) obj).getMsg());
            }
            return message2List;
        }
    });
```

I used the previouse code, but it seems that there is something wrong, as the log messages never printed. What should I do to execute all observables in the list?

Comment: Please use as doOnNext on obs1 and obs2 in order to log items. It looks like one of the given observabeles does not emit any values.

Comment: Thank you @HansWurst for your comment, it was my fault, all observable emit values, the problem is that I am calling network operation on main thread :))) !! stupid me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    Observable<Msg> obs1 = getObs1();
    Observable<Msg> obs2 = getObs2();

    List<Observable<Msg>> listOfObs = new ArrayList<Observable<Msg>>();
    listOfObs.add(obs1.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()));
    listOfObs.add(obs2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()));

    Observable allObs = Observable.zip(listOfObs, new FuncN<List<Msg>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Msg> call(Object... args) {
            List<Msg> message2List = new ArrayList<Msg>();
            for (Object obj : args) {
                message2List.add((Msg) obj);
                Log.d("Msg>>>", ((Msg) obj).getMsg());
            }
            return message2List;
        }
    });
    allObs.toBlocking().single();
```

Comment: use subscribeOn to run process on a separate thread. Do not forget to toBlocking().single() or .subscribe() to actually run the process.